# wordpress / css - what is the code for a "return" key press

Tags: css, wordpress

So as most developers, i use a CSS RESET in all my work. One of the small problems i run into is that when developing custom anything in wordpress, i use this reset and the problem ive been having is that, because of said reset when the user is writing a post, the ability to for example, use italics / bold etc isnt available. I mean it is but its not applied because of said reset.

I just went in and removed the `em` / `i` / `b` etc tags from the reset block and its working BUT, theres one more thats giving me the biggest problem and thats that when someone hits the enter key to create space between text etc, nothing happens. they have to manually go in and put in `<br/>` tags to create the separation.

That said, it got me to thinking that....what exactly IS the css for line breaks/ the enter key?

below is whats in my CSS reset...not sure what else i have to remove.

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn,  img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, sub, sup, tt, var, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

a{text-decoration:none;}
```

Ive tried to google but, aside from the p tag or the div tag etc...not sure what i have to remove to get the enter key/space created by pressing the enter key to go back to default.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: whitespace is normalized in HTML, the default behavior is to display any whitespace (including CR/LF) as a single space.  You'd need to add something to the text to create the breaks (such as the `br`, `p`, or `div` tags you mentioned).

Comment: In what context are you having this problem? Are you resetting the admin CSS? If not, where/how are your users writing posts? Of course, if you reset 'em', 'i', and 'b', they won't display as anything special. You have to add your own rules for them. 

I have never had an issue with the return key not working. That has me puzzled, but again, what is the context in which you see this?

Comment: Well i removed the styling tags from the reset so those are fine. The return key, what happens is, ill be on plain text mode for example and say i want to split a paragraph. When i hit enter at the point i want to split it, and hit update, the page reloads and puts everything the way it was b4 i hit enter. when i reload on the front side of the site nothing has changed either. If i go to wordpress default install and do the same thing, it gives me the space like normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create separation such as a return, you can use a :after or :before like this:

```
    p:after {
        content: '\13';
        display: block;
    }
```

This will create a new line before of each paragraph element. You can use this trick with any kind of element.
Here's the fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/napy84/VQLTq/